# Why Does only gif images aren't loading in my webview android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, web-applications, android-webview

I'm making a webapp and the webview of android studio isn't loading a particular gif but it loads all other images and gifs, but while the website loads the gif as usual. i had made the javascript  in the website to show it until another image is loaded.

i tried `settings.domStorageEnabled = true` 
and it doesn't seem to help ! please help me figure out what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below cod snippet to load the .gif into webview:

1. Create a html file like this:

   [image]
2. And store it in "assets" folder of you application also store your gif in the same folder. And do following to show it:

   webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your_html.html");

**Other option is use the below library:**

https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Comment: but how does it load from my website? my website will sense it like my. website.com/file:///android ect..